# Значення слова "наповиди"

Tags: значення-слів

У вірші "ЗГАДКА ЗА МАРКІЯНА ШАШКЕВИЧА ВО ВІЧНУЮ ЄГО ПАМ’ЯТЬ" М. Устияновича зустрів такі рядки:

> В тій гадці жив-єсь, віддихав-єсь нею,
>
> В ній твоє щастє, печалі, надії,
>
> **Снів наповиди**, і радощі з нею,
>
> І тая тоска, в котрій боліє

В СУМі такого слова немає, немає його і в [Вільному тлумачному українському словнику](http://sum.in.ua/f/napovydy). Як я розумію, слово вже давно перестало використовуватися в нашій мові, однак хотілося б дізнатися його значення і якщо можливо етимологію (пошуки в [ЕСУМ](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_2003/EtSlUkrM_2003.pdf) також нічого не дали).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У   монографії   [Микола Лесюк СТАНОВЛЕННЯ І РОЗВИТОК

УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ ЛІТЕРАТУРНОЇ 
МОВИ В ГАЛИЧИНІ](http://shron1.chtyvo.org.ua/Lesiuk_Mykola/Stanovlennia_i_rozvytok_ukrainskoi_literaturnoi_movy_v_Halychyni.pdf) знаходимо примітку автора, що **наповидами = спогадами**

У [Словнику  фізичної термінології](https://issuu.com/iend/docs/slovnyk_fizuchnoyi_terminologiyi/167) знаходимо **наповид - див. мираж.** У статті **мариво** - мана, омана, наповид.

На жаль, інформації щодо етимології цього слова не знайшла.

Answer (score 2):

У статті [«Рідкісні українські слова» на сайті Мислене древо](http://www.myslenedrevo.com.ua/uk/Sci/Linguistics/RareWords/N.html) написано:

> Наповиди — **сновидіння** (різні автори)
>   <sub>[У дужках після кожного пояснення стаття наводить імена авторів, що вживали відповідне слово.]</sub>

Хоч ця стаття не дуже надійне джерело (невідомо, хто її писав і на що сприпався), але з контексту бачимо, що приблизно в такому значенні це слово вживається в деяких творах:

1. Яків Головацький «Историческій очеркъ основанія Галицко-рускои Матицѣ и справозданье первого собору ученыхъ и любителей народного просвѣщенія» (Львів, 1850) [[на Google Книгах № 1](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=HdIJAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA7&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8), [на Google Книгах № 2](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=Jk5dAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA7&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8)]:

   > Єсть въ народѣ пѣсня, що мати дѣтинѣ надъ колискою спѣває проста и непоказьна, а звукъ єи товаришитъ намъ солодкими *наповидами* до гробу и милѣйшая надъ всякіи согла́сы чудесныхъ напѣво̂въ.
2. Михайло Яцків «Огні горять» (Львів, 1902) [[у бібліотеці «Чтиво»](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Yatskiv/Ohni_horiat/)]:

   > Нїна опинила ся в лїсї і паде на виверть [ялицю, вивернену від бурі]. У голові шумить, серце бє ся, живчики стукають, перед її очима затремтїли *наповиди*.
   >
   > Палати з ґотийськими склепінями і колюмнадами <…>.
   >
   > Нараз збудив її гомін гурту <…>.

Я припускаю, що значення слова може бути дещо ширшим, ніж лише «сновидіння». На це натякає словосполучення *снів наповиди* — якщо наповиди є явищем, пов'язаним лише зі сном, то навіщо вточнювальне слово *снів* (хоча це може бути й фігурою мовлення). Можливо, слово *наповиди* також може позначати марення, галюцинації тощо (як на це натякає [інша відповідь](/a/4928)). Можливо, наповиди — це **видіння** (в будь-якому сенсі), а снів наповиди — вже сновидіння.

Однак книга [«Письменники Західної України 30-50-х років XIX ст.» (Київ, 1965)](http://litopys.org.ua/zahpysm/zah.htm), що наводить зокрема й [відповідний вірш Устияновича](http://litopys.org.ua/zahpysm/zah17.htm#page305), у розділі «Пояснення слів» теж [пише](http://litopys.org.ua/zahpysm/zah28.htm#page635):

> Наповиди — сновидіння.

Висновок: чи справді *наповиди* означає здебільшого «сновидіння», чи значення цього слова ширше (наприклад, будь-які «видіння»), просто занадто вузьке його  пояснення з книги «Письменники Західної України 30-50-х років XIX ст.» (що, можливо, пояснювало конкретний ужиток у контексті, а не значення слова загалом) потім перекочувало в інші місця, — мені важко сказати.